# Why does containsKey(String) return false in my program,though the key is present and identical?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I am writing a program that reads lines from a file. 
The `HashMap<String,Class>` is being used. For example, The key used is "inboundtcp". 
When reading the first line from buffered reader, containsKey(key) of hashmap returns false and a new entry is added, the obvious case. However, if there is another line with key "inboundtcp", containskey(key) returns false.
 I put a breakpoint and saw that the hashCode are being different. It gets added as a new entry. For All other subsequent reads, after the second read, from the file, containsKey(key) returns true

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
            String trafficDirection=fields[0].trim();
            String trafficProtocol=fields[1].trim();
            String portValue=fields[2];
            String ipAddressValue=fields[3].trim();
            String key=trafficDirection+trafficProtocol;
            if(rulesMap.containsKey(key)){
                PortsAndIP result=insertPortAndIPAddress(portValue,ipAddressValue);
                ArrayList<PortsAndIP> existingData= (ArrayList<PortsAndIP>) rulesMap.get(trafficDirection+trafficProtocol);
                existingData.add(result);
                rulesMap.put(new String(trafficDirection+trafficProtocol),existingData);
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<PortsAndIP> data= new ArrayList<PortsAndIP>();
                PortsAndIP result=insertPortAndIPAddress(portValue,ipAddressValue);
                if(result!=null) {
                    data.add(result);
                    rulesMap.put(new String(trafficDirection+trafficProtocol),data);
                }
              }
            }
```

I referred all the relevant posts, but could not get a solution. The String class already implements hashCode() and equals() method, but why does this  happen?

Comment: If the strings' hashcodes are different, then the strings are different, even if they *look* the same. Some characters look like other characters. Some characters are invisible. You need to look harder at the exact content of the strings.

Comment: Not that it would affect the behavior of the HashMap, but it's completely pointless to write `new String(trafficDirection+trafficProtocol)`. Just write `trafficDirection+trafficProtocol`

Comment: @Eran I was just testing to check if key matches. Writing without new() is the one I do usually.

Comment: @khelwood I am read the line from csv file with exact word. Can you tell me some methods to check for more robust equality?

Comment: If you have the two strings you think should be equal but are not, look at them character by character in your debugger.

Comment: @khelwood If you saw my code, hashmap only adds the key as its entry in the first time, The second time when it reads from csv, it fails and added as new entry. The third and so forth times, containsKey(key) works.  So you say that first time and second time the keys are different?

Comment: I'm telling you that if you have two strings with different hashcodes, then they're different, however you got them.

Comment: @khelwood I get that and I knew this fact....I want to know why or how to debug them if they look alike..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my csv was in utf-8 bytes .csv format. When I changed to .csv format in MS-Excel, the hashmap was able to return true for the key.